# Why isn't rspec being more verbose?

Tags: rspec

When I raise an expectation that fails, I get output like this

```
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector 'div.panel.panel-error', text: "asd" }
       expected #has_selector?("div.panel.panel-error", {:text=>"asd"}) to return true, got false
```

This makes debugging a **real** nighmare, especially when the  text is simply capitalized or has a stupid spelling mistake in it. How can I get rspec to give me output like this:

```
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector 'div.panel.panel-error', text: "asd" }
       expected #has_selector?("div.panel.panel-error", {:text=>"asd"}) to contain "You don't exist in our system!" true, got "You do not exist in Our system."
```

Is this a format option I can add to my `.rspec` file?

Here's how mine currently looks:

```
--color
--drb
--order default

--format progress
--format documentation
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a problem with your rspec config, its more to do with the kind of assertion that you are making. You are asking Capybara to find an element that matches a CSS selector with an element type of `div`, two classes and the given text. The CSS selector is just going to return no match because only two out of three parts of the selector match, and because it never retrieved the element that matches `div.panel.panel-error` it can't compare the strings.

To get the more helpful kind of output that you want, you would need to select the element by element and class, i.e. `div.panel.panel-error` and then assuming that is present you can assert that the text is what it should be. Try:

```
find('div.panel.panel-error').text.should == 'asd'
```

The two step version is not quite so elegant though because you are not making a direct assertion on the subject of the test (the `page`).